# Adding two 16-bit integers to produce a 16-bit answer in 6502?

Tags: assembly, byte, addition, 6502

I needed to add two 16 bit integers to produce a 16-bit answer using absolute mode addressing. I, however, messed up the memory addresses and can't figure out why. Please advise me on correcting my code:

```
x1 = $0410
y2 = $0411
s1 = $0412

Start at $0500

CLC             18
LDA     x1      AD  10  04
ADC     y1      6D  11  04
STA     s1      8D  12  04
LDA     x1+1    AD  11  04
ADC     y2+1    6D  12  04
STA     s1+1    8D  13  04
BRK             00
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a 16-bit integer takes two bytes, your locations overlap. You need to space them two bytes apart:

```
x1 = $0410
y2 = $0412
s1 = $0414
```

Comment: So I would have to change the high bytes of x1+1, y2+1, and s1+1 to 12, 13, and 14?

Comment: The high bytes? They are all only one byte, so that doesn't make any sense. Edited answer to make it clearer.

Comment: Oh I see... that would make it look like the edited version, correct?

Comment: Yes, it should work now. But please don't correct the code in your question as it would not correspond to the question any more.